# Append data to iterator in struts2

Tags: struts2, iterator

Hi friends i am trying to create facebook like pagination in struts2
what i am trying is at the end of the webpage i am calling action class using javascript ajax using below code

```html
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
      console.log("Bottom reached");
      var ul = $('.ullist');
      var start = ul.children().length;
      $.post("postImage.action?", { start: start }, function(session2) {
        // Here I am getting json data 
        alert("inside class " + session2);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Bottom reached not");
    } 
  });
</script>
```

The problem is that I have already a list using iterator. Please tell me how to append the value to iterator.

```
 <s:iterator value="#session.list">
       .......//here i already have data
 </s:iterator>
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, how is that iterator related to the first code (javascript) block?

Comment: here postImage.action class is called when scroll reach the end of webpage. This class  return session data ,now i want to append it to iterator list please tell me how to do that.or my way is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You don't "append data to the iterator", you append DOM elements to the DOM.

You have two main options:

1. Return rendered HTML and append it at the end of the page (wherever is appropriate in your DOM), or...
2. Return JSON (or XML or whatever) and build the DOM dynamically on the client side.

You already have a JSP that renders the same type of information, I'd re-use that chunk of JSP, return rendered HTML, and append it. That said, there are countless jQuery bottomless pagination examples and many plugins–I'd probably just pick one that gets you started and take it from there, and use whatever mechanism your choice uses.